# R apply statement does not work with a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum, apply

I'd like to know the reason why the following does not work on the matrix structure I have posted [here](http://alrig.com/code/MyMatrix.R) (I've used the dput command).

When I try running:

```
apply(mymatrix, 2, sum)
```

I get:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

However, when I check to make sure it's a matrix I get the following:

> is.matrix(mymatrix)

```
[1] TRUE
```

I realize that I can get around this problem by unlisting the data into a temp variable and then just recreating the matrix, but I'm curious why this is happening.

Comment: Note that the error isn't about `apply`- rather, it's thrown when `sum` is applied to the columns of the matrix. (You can run `apply(mymatrix, 2, identity)` without throwing an error)

Comment: @DavidRobinson You might not get an error but you also might not get what was desired.

Comment: @DWin: I didn't mean that this was a substitute- I meant to emphasize where the error was being thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?is.matrix` says:

> 'is.matrix' returns 'TRUE' if 'x' is a vector and has a '"dim"'
>   attribute of length 2) and 'FALSE' otherwise.

Your object is a list with a dim attribute.  A list is a type of vector (even though it is not an atomic type, which is what most people think of as vectors), so `is.matrix` returns `TRUE`.  For example:

```
> l <- as.list(1:10)
> dim(l) <- c(10,1)
> is.matrix(l)
[1] TRUE
```

To convert `mymatrix` to an atomic matrix, you need to do something like this:

```
mymatrix2 <- unlist(mymatrix, use.names=FALSE)
dim(mymatrix2) <- dim(mymatrix)
# now your apply call will work
apply(mymatrix2, 2, sum)
# but you should really use (if you're really just summing columns)
colSums(mymatrix2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The elements of your matrix are not `numeric`, instead they are `list`, to see this you can do:

```
apply(m,2, class) # here m is your matrix
```

So if you want the column sum you have to 'coerce' them to be `numeric` and then apply `colSums` which is a shortcut for `apply(x, 2, sum)`

```
colSums(apply(m, 2, as.numeric)) # this will give you the sum you want.
```